# How to get data from xml in Swift

Tags: swift, xml, xml-parsing

I want to get a service response from XML.I tried '`SWXMLHash`'
 ,'`SwiftyXMLParser`'.

I need this value: `Device is  Registered`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body> 
<QR_GetDeviceCheckAndRegistrationResponse 
xmlns="http://www.bdmitech.com/m2b"> 
<QR_GetDeviceCheckAndRegistrationResult>Device is 
Registered</QR_GetDeviceCheckAndRegistrationResult> 
</QR_GetDeviceCheckAndRegistrationResponse></soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? What exactly do you need help with? Please post the code you need help with or have you mistaken stackoverflow with free code writing service?

Comment: "i try 'SWXMLHash' ,'SwiftyXMLParser'" <--- And what happened? You didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to just use `XMLParser`, you’d define a delegate object:

```
class ParserDelegate: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    var currentValue: String?
    var registrationResult: String?

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if elementName == "QR_GetDeviceCheckAndRegistrationResult" {
            currentValue = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        currentValue? += string
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "QR_GetDeviceCheckAndRegistrationResult" {
            registrationResult = currentValue
            currentValue = nil
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
        print(parseError)
    }
}
```

And then you’d parse:

```
let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
let parserDelegate = ParserDelegate()
parser.delegate = parserDelegate
guard 
    parser.parse(),
    let result = parserDelegate.registrationResult
else { return }
print(result)
```